# Filter pages with multiple tags in Umbraco 4.7

Tags: umbraco

I want to put check boxes on my page, corresponding to certain tags.
Then I want the user to be able to filter out articles depending on what checkboxes are ticked.
For example: The user wants to read about apples and oranges and therefore ticks both "apples" and "oranges", The result should be articles where both are tagged,  but not only apples or only oranges.

Any idea how I can do this in Umbraco?
I'm using umbraco 4.7

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this. The easiest (but not most scalable) would be to create a checkbox datatype called "fruit". This would be added to all Document types you wanted to be able to filter.

You could then use XLST/XPATH to filter the document types to those with selected fruits.

**Edit:**

The XSLT you would need to access and display the selected fruit tags for a specific article would be something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="items" select="umbraco.library:Split($fruit,',')" />
<xsl:for-each select="$items//value">
   <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(current())"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In the context of filtering a collection of articles, you could use adapt this code to be something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage//Article [umbraco.library:Split(./fruit,',')//value = 'orange']">
   <xsl:value-of select="./@nodeName"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will find all Article nodes under the current page that have a fruit tag set as 'orange', and then display each Article's title.

Comment: All the articles aldready have tags.
I have no experience with XSLT/XPATH could you perhaps point me in the right direction?
Thanks